# Unable to Stop Testcontainers Container in .NET Using MSTest

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, mstest, testcontainers

I'm using the dotnet `Testcontainers` library to spin up a SQL Server database in Docker for integration testing. I'm using the MSTest framework.

My idea is to run a `TestInitialize` where the container will start, populate the database and run assertions in the test method, and then run a `TestCleanup` at the end which will stop the container and dispose of it.

However, the container starts up in Docker and the test hangs (I guess it never ends up running for some reason). Also I'm not 100% sure how to populate the database (I couldn't find any commands for initialising and SQL scripts).

Here is the code:

```
[TestClass]
public class WithFixtureData
{
    private static readonly TestcontainersContainer _dbContainer =
        new TestcontainersBuilder<TestcontainersContainer>()
        .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server")
        .WithEnvironment("Database", "Master")
        .WithEnvironment("User Id", "SA")
        .WithEnvironment("Password", "YourSTRONG!Passw0rd")
        .WithCleanUp(true)
        .Build();

    [TestInitialize]
    public async Task StartContainer()
    {
        await _dbContainer.StartAsync();
        ///container starts
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public async Task ShouldBringCorrectFixturesBack()
    {
        ///populate db and run assertions. This code never seems to run
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public async Task DisposeContainer()
    {
        await _dbContainer.StopAsync();
        ///this part of the code never seems to be executed either
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your container even building and starting? If you read the [mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) documentation you need to be supplying at least `.WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y")` and `.WithEnvironment("MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD", "YourSTRONG!Passw0rd")` to it. To be accessible from outside the container you probably also need `.WithExposedPorts(1433)`, or similar, and then `.WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilPortIsAvailable(1433))` to wait until the SQL Server service is listening on that port and is ready to accept connections.

Comment: You should populate your database with whatever mechanism you would normally use. Testcontainers' job is only to give you a container with a running database instance.

Comment: @KevinWittek Yup understood... It's just I'm trying to set up the test so it starts a container when the test class initializes, and then stops it after all the methods are run.

Comment: You say it hangs. Does this mean it hangs indefinitely? Because you should eventually run into a timeout. Sharing the container logs can also help with debugging. Besides, see the previous comment regarding using the correct WaitStrategy. You can find a working example in this blog post: https://www.atomicjar.com/2022/10/hello-dotnet/

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering how the example above even runs, the configuration looks wrong. I attached a working example below, but first, lets take a look into the issues:

1. The environment variables do not exist. The `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` image has the following [environment variables](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) (see section **Environment Variables**) to configure SQL Server on Linux containers. The section **How to use this Image** might also help. To run the container at least these configurations are necessary:

   ```cs
   .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y")
   .WithEnvironment("MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD", "yourStrong(!)Password")
   ```
2. The database port is not exposed, you cannot connect to the database. To expose and bind a container port to a random public host port use `.WithPortBinding(1433, true)`. [Here](https://dotnet.testcontainers.org/api/create_docker_container/#examples) is another example that shows how to expose a container port.
3. Your configuration does not use a wait strategy to indicate readiness of the service running inside the container. A wait strategy for SQL Server could be something like:

   ```cs
   .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilCommandIsCompleted("/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd", "-S", "localhost,1433", "-U", "sa", "-P", "yourStrong(!)Password"))
   ```

A working configuration will look something like:

```cs
[TestClass]
public sealed class SO
{
  private const string Database = "master";

  private const string Username = "sa";

  private const string Password = "yourStrong(!)Password";

  private const ushort MssqlContainerPort = 1433;

  private readonly TestcontainersContainer _dbContainer =
    new TestcontainersBuilder<TestcontainersContainer>()
      .WithImage("mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest")
      .WithPortBinding(MssqlContainerPort, true)
      .WithEnvironment("ACCEPT_EULA", "Y")
      .WithEnvironment("MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD", Password)
      .WithWaitStrategy(Wait.ForUnixContainer().UntilCommandIsCompleted("/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd", "-S", $"localhost,{MssqlContainerPort}", "-U", Username, "-P", Password))
      .Build();

  [TestInitialize]
  public Task StartContainer()
  {
    return _dbContainer.StartAsync();
  }

  [TestCleanup]
  public Task DisposeContainer()
  {
    return _dbContainer.StopAsync();
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public Task Question_74323116()
  {
    var connectionString = $"Server={_dbContainer.Hostname},{_dbContainer.GetMappedPublicPort(MssqlContainerPort)};Database={Database};User Id={Username};Password={Password};";

    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      try
      {
        sqlConnection.Open();
      }
      catch
      {
        Assert.Fail("Could not establish database connection.");
      }
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }
}
```